# The [virtual-method] tag should be a synonym of [virtual-functions]

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

When I try to suggest to make [virtual-method](/questions/tagged/virtual-method) a synonym of [virtual-functions](/questions/tagged/virtual-functions), I get an error message about a reverse synonym:

[image: synonym suggestion]

The reason seems to be that [virtual-method](/questions/tagged/virtual-method) has itself a synonym, [virtual-methods](/questions/tagged/virtual-methods). Both of those tags should be made synonyms of [virtual-functions](/questions/tagged/virtual-functions).